# Adding IPs to Keepalived

Tags: linux, keepalived

What is the proper way to add IP addresses to a keepalived `vrrp_instance` without have the IPs flop around or drop for a second?

Answer (score 4):

Simply `killall -HUP keepalived`

However it has to be done on all servers at roughly the same time as there is the transmission of the count of IPs for a VRRP. ("receive an invalid ip number count associated with VRID")

Comment: What happens when this stays off for too long?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you want to hear as it's a bit of a fudge I think, but I wanted to share an idea with you (as I don't believe there is any supported way of doing this, i.e. having a running `keepalived` process reload it's config).

You could manually add the IP's to the `keepalived` interface on the VRRP master using CLI, so assume server1 eth1 is 192.168.0.1 and server2 eth1 is 192.168.0.2, and they both have 192.168.0.254 in `keepalived`. On server1;

```
sudo ip a a 192.168.0.253/24 dev eth1
```

The master now has the additional IP(s).

On server2, make the changes to `keepalived` config, add in the new IPs, add them under virtual_ipaddress_excluded, as per [this SF query](https://serverfault.com/questions/334197/keepalived-for-more-than-20-virtual-addresses).

Now bounce `keepalived` process on server2, the backup server.

Now add the IP(s) into server1 `keepalived` confif but don't bounce the daemon, as that will cause downtime. If/when the day comes your master `keepalived` box enters the fail over state and the server2 becomes master, bounce `keepalived` on server1 then to reload the config (assuming you're not using preempt, server1 will now wait to become master again, and both boxes have the new IP(s) configured).

That is the only way I can see to do this. I'd like to hear a method for making a running `keepalived` reload it's config if anyone has such a method.