# Meaning of virtual_ipaddress_excluded in keepalived configuration

Tags: load-balancing, keepalived, vrrp

I had some problems with my keepalived configuration and found the answer in this post: [Keepalived for more than 20 virtual addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/334197/keepalived-for-more-than-20-virtual-addresses)

But I am not sure about the difference between virtual_ipaddress and virtual_ipaddress_excluded? Can anyone explain this to me? The doc says:

> virtual_ipaddress_excluded { # VRRP IP excluded from VRRP packets

Answer (score 1):

**virtual_ipaddress** and **virtual_ipaddress_excluded** both list IP addresses that keepalived may bring up and down on the server but those defined as *excluded* (i.e. listed in **virtual_ipaddress_excluded**) are not listed in the [VRRP packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3768#section-5) itself
([source](https://e-mc2.net/keepalived-documentation-nightmare)).

Apart from this, I'd be curious to know the purpose of listing / not listing the VIPs in the VRRP packets. Maybe it's just a matter of packet size / amount of traffic, since **virtual_ipaddress_excluded** is not limited to 20 IP addresses.

Comment: The [keepalived.conf(5) manual page](http://www.keepalived.org/manpage.html) says it's a matter of traffic: "For cases with large numbers (eg 200) of IPs on the same interface. To decrease the number of packets sent in adverts, you can exclude most IPs from adverts." It also mentions a secondary IPv4+IPv6 use case.